# reduce suggestions bing API

Tags: javascript, bing-api

If you visit this site: [Bing search](http://www.istartedsomething.com/livesearch/#)

You will see (after typing a letter) a list of suggestions which is always about eight suggestions. How can I reduce the number of suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a line of code in your livesearch.js script that looks like this:

```
$.each(suggestResults, function(i,suggestResult){
```

Update it to look like this:

```
$.each(suggestResults.slice(0,3), function(i,suggestResult){
```

Where 3 is the maximum number of suggestions you want to see.